# How to post data from form in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make a user registration router in express. The backend seemed to work fine since I verified it using it postman. However, when I tried to add the front end to it(adding form), I got an error saying
`{"errors":[{"location":"body","param":"name","msg":"Name is required"},{"location":"body","param":"email","msg":"Please include a valid email"},{"location":"body","param":"password","msg":" Please enter a password with 6 or more characters"}]}` Since I included `name` attribute in each input tag, I could not figure out where is the problem.

Here is some part of my codes.

server.js

```
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));
```

users.js

```
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    check('name', 'Name is required')
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check(
      'password',
      ' Please enter a password with 6 or more characters'
    ).isLength({ min: 6 })
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }
.
.
.
```

register.handlebars

```
<form class="form" action="/api/users" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" requried>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" minlength="6">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create account" class="button green-button" />
            </form>ss
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use body-parser
middleware with express

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: Since it works in Postman, I don't think body-parser is the cause of the error here.

Comment: then add enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to html form